# Javascript multiple .value on select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I can put a value in a select like this (mark the select option):

```
document.getElementById('language').value = "en";
```

How can I use that on more select option fields?

The Html

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="language" multiple="">
     <option value="de">german</option>
     <option value="en">english</option>
     <option value="tr">turkey</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: you should put that on select tag which carries all options

Comment: Please add your whole code.

Comment: can you please elaborate your question .

Comment: @Ionut sry I added it

Comment: @binariedMe I did that

Comment: Still no Idea what you wish to do here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want certain options to be selected you can use `querySelectorAll()` method to get the options with certain values and use `forEach()` to loop through all the options you have just *queried* and add selected as `true`. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
var languages = ['de', 'tr'];
for(var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++){
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('#language option[value="' + languages[i] + '"]');
  all.forEach(function(element){
    element.selected = true;
  });
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="language" multiple="">
     <option value="de">german</option>
     <option value="en">english</option>
     <option value="tr">turkey</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: how do I put a js variable instead of `"de"` ?

Comment: @J.Alan, see my updated answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: it worked thanks. I tried to put a php variable which contains an array (holding the languages) to a js var. Then I put the js var(array) in this function, but it did not work. Any idea why?

Comment: If I console.log that php to js array it contains this: `["bg", "da"]` so it should work or?

Comment: @J.Alan, have you used `var languages = <?php echo json_encode($your_array); ?>`? You can't directly pass an PHP array to JavaScript, you will have to encode it

Comment: yes I used this `<?php $json  = json_encode($array) ?>` then   `var array = <?php echo $json ?>;`

Comment: @J.Alan, if the result of `console.log()` is `["bg", "da"]` I can't tell what is happening. I would have to see the whole code. Do you want to discuss this on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138338/discussion-between-ionut-and-j-alan).

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an array instead of a string to jQuery's `val()`.

```js
$('#language').val(["de", "tr"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" id="language" multiple="">
     <option value="de">german</option>
     <option value="en">english</option>
     <option value="tr">turkey</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I do not understand, can you provide an example script with multiple values?

Comment: You can't select multiple values in a select tag. This tag is typically used for dropdowns. You can't have multiple values selected in a dropdown menu.

Comment: @ShreyanshGandhi of course you can: `<select multiple="true">`